# ¿Puedo mostrar más de 10 columnas en dataTables?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, datatables

estoy haciendo uso de dataTables, y necesito mostrar más de 10 columnas en pantalla, pero por más que he intentado no logro hacer que se vean todas las columnas, no sé si haya una manera de poder lograrlo. He aquí mi código:

Llamo mi dataTable en Jquery:

```
//llamado a datatables
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.table').dataTable();
});
```

Este es mi HTML (estoy trabajando con Django):

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <th>Fecha</th>
        <th>Hora Llenado</th>
        <th>Placa</th>
        <th>Piloto</th>
        <th>Ruta</th>
        <th>Serie Factura</th>
        <th>No. Factura</th>
        <th>Total Llenado</th>
        <th>Galones Llenados</th>
        <th>Tipo Combustible</th>
        <th>No. Bomba</th>
        <th>Precio Por Galon</th>
        <th>Kilometraje Inicial</th>
        <th>Kilometraje Final</th>
        <th>Recorrido</th>
        <th>Rendimiento Por Galon</th>
        <th>Manifiesto</th>
        <th>Observaciones</th>
        <th>Estado</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for item in obj %} 
        <tr>
            <td> {{ item.fecha | date:'d-m-y'}}</td>
            <td> {{ item.hora_llenado | title}}</td>
            <td> {{ item.placa | title}}</td>
            <td> {{ item.piloto | title}}</td>
            <td> {{ item.ruta | title}}</td>
            <td> {{ item.serie | title}}</td>
            <td> {{ item.no_factura | title}}</td>
            <td> Q. {{ item.total | intcomma }}</td>
            <td> {{ item.galones | title}}</td>
            <td> {{ item.tipo_combustible | title}}</td>
            <td> {{ item.bomnba | title}}</td>
            <td> Q. {{ item.precioxgalon | intcomma }}</td>
            <td> {{ item.kminicial | title}}</td>
            <td> {{ item.kmfinal | title}}</td>
            <td> {{ item.recorrido | title}}</td>
            <td> {{ item.rendimiento | title}}</td>
            <td> {{ item.manifiesto | title}}</td>
            <td> {{ item.observaciones | title}}</td>
            <td onclick="inactivar({{item.id}})">{#item.estado|yesno:"Activo,Inactivo"#}
            {% if item.estado %}
            <i class="far fa-thumbs-up text-primary"></i>
            {% else %}
            <i class="far fa-thumbs-down text-danger"></i>
            {% endif %}
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: Captura de como se ve mi tabla]
La única manera que he logrado que se logren visualizar todas las columnas es poniendole un `zoom: 80%` al `table`. De esta manera:

```
.table{
   zoom: 80%;
}
```

Espero alguien me pueda ayudar, Gracias de antemano!.

Comment: Has probado a establecer manualmente los anchos de las columnas? Prueba también la clase `compact` de datatables para intentar reducir un poco los paddings.

Comment: Si, ya he intentado eso, y ya están al ancho minimo. Probaré esa clase que dices.

Comment: Si estás usando bootstrap, como parece, tienes la clase [table-responsive](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/tables/#always-responsive) para que al menos te muestre una barra horizontal y puedas desplazarte con ella.  Fíjate bien en el enlace donde se parecia que esa clase debe envolver a la clase table.